# How can I skip the sysprep step and just capture an image?

Tags: disk-image, sysprep, sccm-2012

Ok the problem is, I am troubleshooting a problem with network connectivity when booting into the PE capture media (and only that PE).  I only know how to use the capture media for SCCM, so each time I use it, it does a sysprep.  I can't really troubleshoot this issue unless I skip the sysprep so I don't use up all three tries.

How can I skip the sysprep and just boot into the capture media's PE?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I googled, and the short version is that you use [MDT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dn475741) to create a toolkit that SCCM runs.  I don't know if that would interfere with what you're testing, though, because it sounds like you're testing the capture media's PE.

Speaking as a non-SCCM user, I've been known to boot into PXE and the capture media that way, so maybe that's a better way to go for you.

(Sadly, if there's a "just don't use sysprep!" checkbox, my googling can't find it.)

Comment: Could you get me a quick rundown on how to capture an image manually from a PE (not PXE) that will work using SCCM task sequence?  If there's a way I mean.  Maybe that would work.  Deployment uses task sequence though, so it has to be compatible with that.

Comment: Er.  I'm a WDS/Altiris user, not a SCCM user.  But if you have a PE environment with ImageX, or can map a drive with a copy of ImageX on it from PE, you could run something like `imagex /capture c: e:\test\test.wim "Test Image" /verify`.